# Git rebase -i not in terminal / only works with sudo

Tags: git, vim, ubuntu, git-rebase

I simply want to edit some commits with `git rebase -i HEAD~2` inside the current branch.
I use Ubuntu 10.10 and had to install gvim first to make the command work.
Afterwards, the command opens a gvim window with the normal rebase content.
But when I want to save the file gvim says

> ".git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" E212

[Cannot open file to write]

Also the rebase command finishes right after starting (with `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.`).

- When doing the same command with `sudo` the rebase works, but afterwards it occurs that files are owned by root and I have no write permissions anymore.
- On my ArchLinux system gvim is opened directly in the terminal where I run `git rebase -i` and everything works.
- I tried different terminals (Gnome terminal, LXTerminal, XTerm) - always the same problem

What is the problem here and how to solve it? It should work without sudo.

### Edit 1

- Some files in `.git/...` are owned by root and are read-only. All directories and files in the first level of `.git/` are owned by me. With `ls -l --recursive .git/ | grep root` I tried to detect which files that are but the output does not give the paths of the files...
- Should all files in `.git/` belong to the user? May this be the reason for the problem?

### EDIT 2

- Even after changing ownership and write permissions of all files inside `.git` to user with `sudo chown -R user:user .git/` and `chmod u+w -R .git/` (`ls -l` now shows sth. like `-rw-r--r-- 1 user user`) the problem stays the same.

Comment: Could you change the owner of that file back to you?

Comment: Sure, with sudo, would it be possible that not?

Comment: Yes, it would be, but would leave a lot of linux users screaming in the dark.

Comment: well the problem is why root owns that file in the first place?

Comment: Check to see who owns all the files in .git.  Usually this sort of thing means someone did something as root earlier and left a root-only file / directory behind.

Comment: Use `find .git -uid 0 -ls` to list all files/directories that are owned by root (uid=0). From your update, looks like someone made some changes using root account (or using sudo) earlier and yes everything inside `.git` should be owned by the user.

Comment: Tried sudo chown -R user:user .git, but didn't work for me, what was your solution? thanks

Comment: Did you run both `chown` and `chmod`? But I think I had no solution for this (was on an Ubuntu machine I do not use often).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My solution was:

Run

```
$ git config --global core.editor "gvim -f"
```

First, I thought it was because my repository was on an ntfs drive so the file permissions wouldn´t work correctly. But even after mounting the drive with correct file permissions the problem stayed the same. Starting *vim* with the `-f` option helps (I read about other people solving it the same way), but I don´t know why.

Comment: This solution also worked for me (without the -f flag). I was experiencing this error on Mac OS X with the sublime editor. Changed to vim and the problem went away. Now to polish my vim skills.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `sudo chown -R user .git` to giver `user` back ownership of the files.  You shouldn't ever need to run `git` with `sudo`, as doing so can result in problems like this.

Comment: I suppose you mean `sudo chown -R user:user .git`?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. changing the permissions in the folder does not eliminate the problem
In my case it is because the umask is set 27 which by default creates files with

-rw-r-----

permissions,
Obviously git tires to create a directory which can't be saved by the user.
This is therefore a bug in git.

Note: I noticed that using the editor vim gets around this bug.
It seems that gedit and kate have problems with the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using  [spf13 conf](http://vim.spf13.com/) and I solved the issue with following steps:

```
rm -rf ~/.vimswap
rm -rf ~/.vimviews
rm -rf ~/.vimbackup
```

It seems that your some rebase process had been broken and remove these dirs can recover it.